# Popover close event

Tags: ios, swift

Thought popovers will be easy :(

In storyboard create two ViewControllers: `GraphicalViewController` and `SettingsViewContoller`

On `GraphicalViewController` I put a button and make an action to `SettingsViewController` with segue: Popover.

I try to implement method that will react on dismiss of popover:

```
class settingsViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let popover = popoverPresentationController? {
            println("delegate test") // Works
            popover.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
        println("close test") // Doesn't work when I tap outside popover
    }

}
```

What's wrong with didDismissPopover?

Answer (score 2):

This should work. I have the exact same setup as you have and this works. Make sure you have set iOS 8 as the deployment target and base SDK.

Comment: But how can I access the GraphicalViewController. What is it for SettingsViewController?

Comment: I worked out, it doesn't work when I disable size classes... Is there any way to implement popover close event without size classes?

Comment: I see, I'm not sure whether this is possible in that case. You may have to implement a regular UIPopoverController.